# Probit Marginal Effects output for Latex

Tags: r, marginal-effects

I am computing probit marginal effects from R `mfx` package. I want to generate Latex code for the marginal effects output. I tried `stargazer` package for OLS and probit coefficients, it works fine for both, however for probit marginal effects (by using `probitmfx` command) it doesn't work.

Please help me in this regard, thanks.

Comment: `xtable` and `Hmisc` packages both have facilities to output Latex tables, but you may need to put together the matrix for output by hand.

Comment: Thanks @Imo, Could you please give a little example, so that i can continue with it.

Comment: Just scroll through [these posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+xtable). You should find quite a few useful examples.

Comment: Thank you, i explored all the links but remained unsucceful.

Comment: I managed to find the answer here [link] (https://www.r-bloggers.com/porting-stata-like-marginal-effects-to-latex/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found an easy solution, but here is the hack that I use:

```
ols <- lm(your_formula, data=your_data, family="binomial")
probit <- glm(your_formula, data=your_data, family="binomial")
probit_margins <- probitmfx(your_formula, your_data, atmean=FALSE)$mfxest
your_table <- stargazer(ols, probit, coef = list(NULL, probit_margins[,1]), 
                                     se = list(NULL, probit_margins[,2]))
```

It works the same with logit, and you don't necessarily want the `atmean=FALSE` option. I included an OLS in the example to show you how to include other specifications that `stargazer` can handle, without the need to specify it the coefficients and standard errors.

Comment: And how would you do if you have two probit models and want to include their marginal effects in the table? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Analogous to bixiou's answer, maybe slightly more elegant (at least we don't fit twice):

```
ols <- lm(your_formula, data=your_data, family="binomial")
probit_margins <- probitmfx(your_formula, your_data, atmean=FALSE)

your_table <- stargazer(ols, probit_margins$fit,
coef = list(NULL, probit_margins$mfxest[,1]),
se = list(NULL, probit_margins$mfxest[,2]))
```

This exploits the fact that a `probitmfx` object's `fit` attribute is the original model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `texreg` ([documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/texreg.pdf)):

```
model <- probitmfx(formula = y ~ x, data = your_data)
texreg(model)
```